# Images on the sides without container

Tags: css, svg

I'd like to have page contents with custom background color centered in viewport to max width 1280px with images on the sides covering the remaining space. I want only semantically relevant HTML like this:

```
<footer>
  My contents
</footer>
```

Not with this meaningless container

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    My contents
  </div>
</footer>
```

The closest I got was this CSS:

```
footer {
  --content-width: min(1280px, 100vw);
  --pspace: calc(50vw - var(--content-width) / 2);
  padding: 0 var(--pspace);
  background: url('/black.png') var(--pspace) 0/var(--content-width) 100% no-repeat,
              url('/image-left.png') left bottom/contain no-repeat, 
              url('/image-right.png') right bottom/contain no-repeat;
}
```

Now instead of black.png (which is a black pixel) I would like to have a solid color covering the contents space (so the images are cut not to display there), but not the sides space (the images are semitransparent), so I guess I can't use `background-color`. I would like to specify the color in `--col-bg` CSS variable. Is there a way to achieve this?

I hoped I could use inline SVG as the background image like this

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1'><path d='M0,0h1v1H0' fill='--col-bg'/></svg>"), ...
```

but the browser doesn't seem to accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    footer {
        --content-width: min(1280px, 100vw);
        --pspace: calc(50vw - var(--content-width) / 2);
        --left: var(--pspace);
        --right: calc(100vw - var(--pspace));
        --bg-color: blue;
  
        padding: 0 var(--pspace);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) var(--left), var(--bg-color) var(--left), var(--bg-color) var(--right), rgba(0,0,0,0) var(--right)),
            url('left.png') right var(--right) bottom/contain no-repeat,
            url('right.png') calc(var(--left) + var(--content-width)) bottom/contain no-repeat;

    }
</style>

<footer>
    My contents
</footer>
```

The footer must be 100vw wide otherwise positioning of the images breaks.

I would strongly recommend (for sanity reasons) the usual approach - `max-width: 1280px; margin: auto; position: relative;` + absolutely positioned `::before, ::after` for those images.